# System.__ComObject in LotusNotes in VB.net when extracting Attachments

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes, attachment, com-object

I want to access a Lotus Notes Database and get attachments from documents in it. 
I can open the DB and doc and loop through all items. 
The problem is, I can not use the items as NotesRichTextItem and therefore not check if there are any item.EmbeddedObject. 
I guess it is a problem with declaration of the items. 
In general: If I debug using VS2010, doc and the database and NotesSession have the "value" System.__ComObject and "type" is the Domino.Notes Object it should be.
e.g. doc in WATCH:

```
Name   VALUE                 TYPE     
doc    {System.__ComObject}  Domino.NotesDocument
```

but if I use the doc.GetType() command the result is

```
doc.GetType()  = {Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}
```

Since I do not know if my doc.item is a NotesRichTextItem, I define it as an object and want to check afterwards is type. Which I can't since the return value of the functions is as above for doc, too. 
Here is the complete code I use currently, I loaded the Lotus Domino reference from the COM section.

```
Public Sub OpenDocumentLN()
        Try
      Dim ns As New Domino.NotesSession
      Dim db As Domino.NotesDatabase
      Dim doc As Domino.NotesDocument
      Dim view As Domino.NotesView

      If Not (ns Is Nothing) Then
        ns.Initialize()
        db = ns.GetDatabase("", sLotusNotesPath & sLotusNotesDB, False)
        If Not (db Is Nothing) Then
          view = db.GetView(sLotusView)
          doc = view.GetFirstDocument
          While Not doc Is Nothing
            Dim lnNextDoc As Domino.NotesDocument = view.GetNextDocument(doc)

            For Each item As Domino.NotesItem In doc.Items
              Dim rtItem As Object = doc.GetFirstItem(item.Name)

              If rtItem Is Nothing Then Continue For
             If Not rtItem.GetType() = GetType(Domino.NotesRichTextItem) Then Continue For
             ' NEVER reach this part of the code since the IF clause prevents it due to the type problem
              If rtItem.EmbeddedObjects Is Nothing Then Continue For
              For Each o As Domino.NotesEmbeddedObject In rtItem.EmbeddedObjects
                o.ExtractFile(sLotusExportPath & o.Source)
              Next

            Next
            doc = lnNextDoc
          End While

        End If
        db = Nothing
        ns = Nothing
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
  End Sub
```

How can I use my rtitem as a NotesRichTextItem so I can handle it appropiate? And why are all objects are treated als ComObjects?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx

Comment: Thank you, using TryCast seems to work. I also found that 'If Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(rtItem) = "IRichTextItem" ' does the trick, but it seems less sound.